# Preventing complex term in a differential equation solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am solving the initial value problem:

$$y'=\frac{t+1}{t(t+4)},\quad y(-1)=0$$

I believe the correct answer is

$$y=\frac14\left[\ln(-t)+3\ln(4+t)-3\ln 3\right]$$

with an interval of existence $(-4,0)$.

I enter:

```
sol = DSolveValue[{y'[t] == (t + 1)/(t (t + 4)), y[-1] == 0}, y, t]
```

And get the response:

```
Function[{t}, 1/4 (-I \[Pi] - 3 Log[3] + Log[t] + 3 Log[4 + t])]
```

I did a little work and convinced myself that $\ln(-t)=\ln(t)-i\pi$ on the interval $(-4,0)$, using the branch $-\pi<\theta\le \pi$, but is there a way to prevent the complex term from appearing in the answer?

Let me also add the plot of the solution.

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Is it true that Mathematica's Plot command just ignores where the function produces complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, as you can see with simple examples such as:  `Plot[Sqrt[x], {x, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: Thanks. I used the code Table[{t, sol[t]}, {t, -4, 0, .25}] // TableForm and all the results were real numbers, whereas Table[{t, sol[t]}, {t, 0, 4, .25}] // TableForm generated all complex numbers and so did Table[{t, sol[t]}, {t, -8,-4, .25}] // TableForm. That's why my plot exists only on (-4,0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eqns = {y'[t] == (t + 1)/(t (t + 4)), y[-1] == 0};

sol = DSolveValue[eqns, y, t]
```

> Function[{t}, (1/4)*((-I)*Pi - 
>           3*Log[3] + Log[t] + 3*Log[4 + t])]

`sol` satisfies the differential equation and boundary condition

```
eqns /. y -> sol // Simplify
```

> {True, True}

So does your formulation

```
sol2 = Function[{t}, 1/4 (Log[-t] + 3 Log[4 + t] - 3 Log[3])];

eqns /. y -> sol2 // Simplify
```

> {True, True}

The two are not equivalent in general

```
sol[t] == sol2[t] //
 FullSimplify[#, Element[t, Reals]] &
```

> I*Pi + Log[-t] == Log[t]

However, they are equivalent for non-positive t

```
sol[t] == sol2[t] // Simplify[#, t <= 0] &
```

> True

To eliminate the complex term restrict the domain to non-positive t

```
sol[t] // Simplify[#, t <= 0] &
```

> (1/4)*(Log[-(t/27)] + 3*Log[4 + t])

Comment: Well done, very nice answer. I can use this to help my students.